# Multithreading in object hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, hierarchy

I'm creating a LOB application in WPF using C# and MVVM.  I have created factories to construct all of my objects and they work ok but they're slow for complex object graphs.  I would like to know if it's advisable to implement asynchronous creation of each level of the complex object's hierarchy.  For example if objA has a large collection of objB and each objB has a large collection of objC, can I asynchronously create the child collections of each type ?  If so how?  I'm new to mutithreaded coding and I'm having trouble picking a direction.  BackgroundWorker vs TPL vs Rx.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use some kind of Lazy-loading technique when you actually access your properties? I personally think that object creation should be as easy as possible and I would (again, personally) try to avoid the multi-threading during object graph creation

Comment: Yeah, what Mikhail said - look at documentation for Lazy<T>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: Multithreading via TPL or Background worker is your choice. And yes they should be implemented to load large number of or heavy (network size) items.

Comment: I looked at Lazy<T> and in my case, it really wouldn't help because the first access happens during the object creation at each level of the hierarchy.

Comment: For multithreading or BackgroundWorker how can each level of the hierarchy notify its parent that it has completed its creation?  Also, will this cause completion of the root to stall until they're all finished?  If so, wouldn't that be the same as implementing the creation of the object graph synchronously?